# Execute method in Java that extends in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an onClick in a java file that I would like to preform an action in my Kotlin file. I'm not sure how to reference the method properly.

Here is the Java onClick code:

```
mCenterImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 1) {
      viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
      CameraFragment.takePicture();
    }
  }
});
```

The Kotlin file is a fragment called "CamreaFragment.kt"

The method I would like to execute is takePicture(). When I follow android studios stuggestion to implement the method, it provides the following code in the CameraFragment.kt:

```
companion object {
  @JvmStatic
  fun takePicture() {

  }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for me, as when I put the code between the brackets in

```
 fun takePicture() { }
```

it does not seem to work, providing errors. So my question is how can I implement a method in an onClick for my Java file that will perform an action in my Kotlin file?

Comment: take a look at this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not this is a Kotlin class, you need an instance of your fragment to call one of its methods. But we typically don't pass fragment instances around because of their lifecycle. Instead, when you add the fragment to your hierarchy, you should give it a tag, and then when you want to call a method on it, find it by tag.

For example:

```
private static final String CAMERA_FRAGMENT_TAG = "CameraFragmentTag";

supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.my_fragmentContainer, CameraFragment(), CAMERA_FRAGMENT_TAG)
    .commit();

CameraFragment fragment = (CameraFragment)supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(CAMERA_FRAGMENT_TAG);
if (fragment != null)
    fragment.takePicture();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, where would I declare these? The java file I am referring to is not the parent to the fragment. So supportFragmentManager is not working

Comment: Then what is it, another fragment?

Comment: So the Java file is essentially a tabView that has a button. This tabView extends a framelayout that is on top of an empty fragment. Below that empty fragment is the CameraFragment constantly running in the background.  Similar to snapchats layout, if this helps

Comment: The class should provide a way for a listener to subscribe to the button press. The Activity or Fragment can register the Activity as a listener to this button press. In the Activity listener, it can call down to the CameraFragment.

Comment: Great! How can I go about doing this? I've been trying to find a solution for some time!

Comment: Would it help if I post this as a separate question @Tenfour04?